# Contenteditable Div in a CSS-Grid reseizing the whole Grid

Tags: css, contenteditable, css-grid

I'm currently working with a contenteditable Div in my CSS-Grid.
I need to have a responsive design and here comes the problem.

So I have the following Grid:

```
      .calculator-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 56px 100px 10vh auto 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

For the 2nd row in the html I did put the following:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="input" name="inputField" class="dontRapeEverything" placeholder ="0">
```

This all works fine until the entered characters exceeds the width of the screen. What I expect it to do is make itscrollable so that the user can scroll left and right but it now ends up extending the Width of my whole Grid which makes it really awkward.

Is there any way to limit the width dynamically? It works fine when I set the width manually to e.g. 400px but not with % or vh.

I'm really clueless whats happening here and any help is appreciated.

Comment: try looking up `minmax()` function, also would be better if you'd include the whole grid markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
grid-template-columns: 100%`
```

worked for me. Apparently that limits the width of my outer grid so nothing inside can grow past it.